# Error while getting Voximplant call recording

Tags: voximplant

Why do I get an Access denied error while trying to get a Voximplant's call recording?
Executing JS command: CreateRecorder with params
`[{id = XbLsgTUlSyyAxa4MSsbkMNOGqAi0jk4BgV42WGFC8b0 ; } ;  {classification = {} ; expireSuffix =  ; hd_audio = false ; language =  ; lossless = false ; name =  ; provider = google ; record_name_prefix =  ; s3 = {} ; secure = false ; transcribe = false ; video = true ; videoopt = {mixing = true ; } ; } ;  ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have secured storage option enabled in your application.
You can disable it (three dots menu in your application) or use authorization to access the records:

https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/managementapi/authorization